# Return cell from another sheet if it contains string in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am working on a school rooming timetable system. I am finding a formula which finds if a particular room is used during a specific period by which class and teacher.

There is a staff overview with clean data of which class and room they are in, alongside preferred results:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9Q8K9KBLgqCsvVZ_ekqsLPbZKeMzvldDnyI-KerOD4/edit?usp=sharing

For example, for on the overview, Monday Period 1 (Column B) Staff 1 uses room BG01 for the class 07MA01. Thus on the room overview, it shows that in Period 1, Staff 1 uses BG01 for 07MA01.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=iferror( 
  textjoin( "; ", true, 
    filter( 
      regexreplace('Staff Overview'!B$3:B, "@.+", "") & "(" & trim('Staff Overview'!$A$3:$A) & ")", 
      regexmatch('Staff Overview'!B$3:B, $A3) 
    ) 
  ),  
  "FREE" 
)
```